# Run python command in laravel with blade form info

Tags: php, python, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-blade

I'm trying to launch a python script with some info stored in a form in laravel 5.6

The form has the following info:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['FormulaController@update', $formula->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{Form::label('tipo', 'Tipo Salida')}}
                    {{Form::select('tipo', ['int', 'float', 'booleano'], $formula->tipo_salida, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'tipo'])}}</td>
            <td colspan="2">{{Form::label('variables', 'Variables')}}
                    {{Form::text('variables', $formula->variables, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'nox,/', 'id' => 'variables'])}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">{{Form::label('formula', 'Fórmula')}}
                        {{Form::text('formula', $formula->formula, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'a*1', 'id' => 'formula'])}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><h6>{{Form::label('Nombreresultado', 'Resultado:')}}</h6></td>
            <td>{{Form::label('resultado', $salida_formula)}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
<a href="/dahs/formulas/{{$formula->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
<input class="btn btn-primary" value="Evaluate" type="button"/>
{{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
{{Form::submit('Guardar', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The idea is that with button 'Evaluate' the page gets the info from the Form's selects and texts and executes a python script like so:

```
$/usr/bin/python /var/www/cgi-bin/evaluate.py 'nox_mgm3;float;a*1.881;nox,/'
```

I've tried several ways, using php code directly into my blade template, javascript, symfony process, but still found that is wird, the code isn't nice, or that maybe is not 'the laravel way'

Is there such a way? Or am I correct in doing it in some of these ways?

Best Regards

Comment: Are you wanting to get data from the form and pass it to your script or execute your script and then display the form?

Comment: The first one, get the data from the form and pass it to the script, I've done this, but then the output from the script should appear in the 'resultado' label when the user clicks the 'Evaluate' button.